# 4 pin microphone SMD pinout indentification

Tags: identification, microphone, pinout

Is there any way to "guess" what's the pinout for microphone without damaging it?

[image]

Better yet do you know what's the pinout for this? (I have searched on the web but most no site provide schematics. (My guess is there is: Vdd, Gnd, In, Out)
Forgot to add that the part in question does NOT have any reference mark (like it is shown in the picture)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this microphone if from a cell phone. It is hard to tell by the picture whether it is a condenser mic or MEMS mic. My guess it is a condenser microphone.

Usually the largest pad(s) is shield. You can assert this by using a multimeter to check if the two bottom pads are connected (0 ohms).

In case of a condenser mic, the top two pads would be the element.

Comment: Yes, this part is used mainly for cell phones (LG GD510), but it's just a mic and can be used anywhere else. Thank you for your input I will give it a try.

Comment: On this note, if you look at the board and the pads, you can see that the bottom two pads are directly connected to the plane on that layer, whereas the top two pads are distinctly separated from that layer and connected with traces to some vias.

Comment: This is almost certainly a MEMS microphone, not a condenser.

Answer (score 0):

With typical MEMS microphones, if you have the contacts facing you, with the entry port (the hole) on the other side upward, pins are numbered anticlockwise from top left.

Thus, in the photo provided, pin 1 is the contact at top left, bottom left is pin 2, bottom right is pin 3, and top right is pin 4.

The two upper contacts with the traces coming out are **V<sub>cc</sub>** on **Pin 1**, **Output** on **Pin 4**, while the remaining contacts are Ground.

Also, see the various Knowles Acoustics MEMS microphones for parts very similar to this one, e.g. [SPQ0410HR5H-B](http://www.knowles.com/search/prods_pdf/SPQ0410HR5H-B.PDF). The one in the question appears to be an older Knowles part, or a clone of one.

Comment: Yes it's very similar in fact after a 4x amplification it seems to be two traces there, thanks for pointing me in the right direction, now I know it's a mems mic. Going to try the pinout configuration.

Comment: @mongoose85 Try with a Vcc of 3.3 Volts to start with, that should work. You would see output on pin 4.